# What do we need to build a multiplayer iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, sql-server, network-programming, multiplayer

I'm doing some work right now for a small startup who wants to build a multiplayer game for the App Store. The basic idea is that users of the game can look to see if anyone else is online and enter a 2 player turn based game.

I have no experience with this kind of thing, so I'm not responsible for that part but we need to know the right kinds of questions to ask potential hires. Does apple provide a framework for what we're trying to achieve? What kind of experience would you expect somebody capable of setting this up and maintaining it to have? I know we'll need an SQL-server to manage accounts and stats and such, but beyond that I'm not too sure.

How would you get started tackling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides Game Center for turn-based multi-player gaming.

you can read about it here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html

Comment: that is great news. I wasn't aware of that, thanks. i hate reinventing the wheel. ;)

Comment: I agree!  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by looking at Apple's Game Center, which was added in iOS 4:  https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/

(You will need an Apple ID to see that page).

Game Center provides much of the framework you're looking for.  (Note:  it's less than a year old, so you may find limited experience with your interviewees).